# Why does the * selector override the class selector?

Tags: css

My question is very simple, why does the text below in the span appear as BLUE color?

I have read this explanation of specificity of selectors (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and it suggests that the * doesn't contribute to specificity. I think that the class selector ".a" is higher specificity and should cause the text in the span to be RED.

I would like to increase my understanding of how the CSS selectors are working here.

```css
* {
   color: blue;
}

.a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
Div
<span>Span</span>
Div
</div>
```

Comment: Because `*` matches all elements. The span element inherits the red color from parent but doesn’t have its own style.

Comment: specifity is only relevant when both selectors target the same element